# Decreasing performance of new JVMs

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jmh

The performance (throughput) of summing all elements in the array in for loop is slower on newer JVMs, than on JVM from Java 1.8.0 JDK. I performed JHM benchmark (plots below). Before each test, sources were compiled by provided javac.exe and run by java.exe, both binaries provided by selected JDK. Tests were performed on Windows 10 and launched by powershell script without any programs running in the background (no other jvms). The computer was equipped with 32GB of RAM, so virtual memory on HDD was not used.

**10M elements in the array:**
[image]

**100M elements in the array:**
[image: JMH benchmark resulrs.]

**Source code of my test:**

```
@Param({"10000000", "100000000"})
public static int ELEMENTS;

public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException, IOException {
    File outputFile = new File(args[0]);

    int javaMajorVersion = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("java.version").split("\\.")[0]);

    ChainedOptionsBuilder builder = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(IteratingBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
            .mode(Mode.Throughput)
            .forks(2)
            .measurementTime(TimeValue.seconds(10))
            .measurementIterations(50)
            .warmupTime(TimeValue.seconds(2))
            .warmupIterations(10)
            .resultFormat(ResultFormatType.SCSV)
            .result(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());

    if (javaMajorVersion > 8) {
        builder = builder.jvmArgs("-Xms20g", "-Xmx20g", "--enable-preview");
    } else {
        builder = builder.jvmArgs("-Xms20g", "-Xmx20g");
    }

    new Runner(builder.build()).run();
}

@Benchmark
public static void cStyleForLoop(Blackhole bh, MockData data) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.randomInts.length; i++) {
        sum += data.randomInts[i];
    }

    bh.consume(sum);
}

@State(Scope.Thread)
public static class MockData {
    private int[] randomInts = new int[ELEMENTS];

    @Setup(Level.Iteration)
    public void setup() {
        Random r = new Random();
        this.randomInts = Stream.iterate(r.nextInt(), i -> i + r.nextInt(1022) + 1).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).limit(ELEMENTS).toArray();
    }
}
```

**Raw data:**

```
JDK 1.8.0_241:
"Benchmark";"Mode";"Threads";"Samples";"Score";"Score Error (99,9%)";"Unit";"Param: ELEMENTS"
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;100;331,446104;5,563589;"ops/s";10000000
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;100;33,757268;0,431403;"ops/s";100000000

JDK 11.0.2:
"Benchmark";"Mode";"Threads";"Samples";"Score";"Score Error (99,9%)";"Unit";"Param: ELEMENTS"
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;100;322,728461;4,823611;"ops/s";10000000
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;100;31,075948;0,062830;"ops/s";100000000

JDK 12.0.1:
"Benchmark";"Mode";"Threads";"Samples";"Score";"Score Error (99,9%)";"Unit";"Param: ELEMENTS"
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;100;322,914782;4,450969;"ops/s";10000000
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;100;31,095232;0,075051;"ops/s";100000000

JDK 13.0.1:
"Benchmark";"Mode";"Threads";"Samples";"Score";"Score Error (99,9%)";"Unit";"Param: ELEMENTS"
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;100;325,103055;4,933257;"ops/s";10000000
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;100;31,228403;0,067954;"ops/s";100000000

JDK 14.0.1:
"Benchmark";"Mode";"Threads";"Samples";"Score";"Score Error (99,9%)";"Unit";"Param: ELEMENTS"
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;100;300,861148;0,443404;"ops/s";10000000
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;100;29,863602;0,035781;"ops/s";100000000

OpenJDK 14.0.2:
"Benchmark";"Mode";"Threads";"Samples";"Score";"Score Error (99,9%)";"Unit";"Param: ELEMENTS"
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;100;300,781930;0,481579;"ops/s";10000000
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;100;29,873509;0,033055;"ops/s";100000000

OpenJDK 15:
"Benchmark";"Mode";"Threads";"Samples";"Score";"Score Error (99,9%)";"Unit";"Param: ELEMENTS"
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;100;343,530895;0,445551;"ops/s";10000000
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;100;34,287083;0,035028;"ops/s";100000000
```

Is there any valid explanation, why newer versions of Java are slower than 1.8 (except OpenJDK 15)?

**UPDATE 1:**

I run same tests for different Xmx/Xms values (for each test Xmx == Xms), results below:

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

- Firstly, I changed `Level.Iteration` to `Level.Trial`.
- Secondly, I forced G1 garbage collector.
- Thirdly, Xmx/Xms was set to 8GB

Results:
[image]

**Raw data:**

```
JDK 1.8.0_241:
"Benchmark";"Mode";"Threads";"Samples";"Score";"Score Error (99,9%)";"Unit";"Param: ELEMENTS"
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;15;33,760346;0,089646;"ops/s";100000000

JDK 11.0.2:
"Benchmark";"Mode";"Threads";"Samples";"Score";"Score Error (99,9%)";"Unit";"Param: ELEMENTS"
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;15;31,075120;0,086171;"ops/s";100000000

JDK 12.0.1:
"Benchmark";"Mode";"Threads";"Samples";"Score";"Score Error (99,9%)";"Unit";"Param: ELEMENTS"
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;15;31,173939;0,044176;"ops/s";100000000

JDK 13.0.1:
"Benchmark";"Mode";"Threads";"Samples";"Score";"Score Error (99,9%)";"Unit";"Param: ELEMENTS"
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;15;31,219283;0,062329;"ops/s";100000000

JDK 14.0.1:
"Benchmark";"Mode";"Threads";"Samples";"Score";"Score Error (99,9%)";"Unit";"Param: ELEMENTS"
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;15;29,808609;0,072664;"ops/s";100000000

OpenJDK 14.0.2:
"Benchmark";"Mode";"Threads";"Samples";"Score";"Score Error (99,9%)";"Unit";"Param: ELEMENTS"
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;15;29,845817;0,074315;"ops/s";100000000

OpenJDK 15:
"Benchmark";"Mode";"Threads";"Samples";"Score";"Score Error (99,9%)";"Unit";"Param: ELEMENTS"
"benchmark.IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop";"thrpt";1;15;34,310620;0,087412;"ops/s";100000000
```

**UPDATE 3:**
I made [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/JakubBialy/javaloopbenchmark) containing benchmark source code, and script to perform benchmark with JMH parameters used by me, which automatically generates plots in png format.
Additionally I performed benchmark on other machine (Linux).
 Results from Linux machine seems to be more optimistic:
[image]

Unfortunately, on my Windows machine, results still show decreasing performance (excluding JDK 15).

**UPDATE 4:**
Results with `-XX:-UseCountedLoopSafepoints`:
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why your random ints are not really random, but ascending (unless overflow occurs)?

Comment: Not really. I wanted to have an array with minimum number of duplicated values. This approach with ascending values with random step seems to be pretty fast to fill the array.

Comment: Why would the number of duplicates matter? Just use `this.randomInts = r.ints(ELEMENTS).toArray();`. It would be interesting whether giving them all the same seed has an impact. I wouldn’t expect any influence of the actual int values on the performance.

Comment: It was essential before because i used this in another test. When i noticed strange performance between different JVMs versions, I cleared code as much as possible and posted here. I agree that is interesting. I will check it later.

Comment: The benchmark scores seem to be poisoned by the GC overhead caused by unnecessary allocations in `setup`. 1) Use `Level.Trial` instead of `Level.Iteration`. 2) Set the same GC on all JDK versions (the default GC differs in JDK 8 vs. 9+)

Comment: @apangin I added benchmark with G1 and Level.Trial. In my opionin, there are no major changes.

Comment: Your title did alarm me, but as of java 15 things seem an improvement over java 8. With semiannual versions that are easy to upgrade, I am relieved again. On lingual changes it is not uncommon for java to become slower for a time.

Comment: Could not reproduce the described behavior. The benchmark works equally fast on JDK 8 and JDK 14 on my Windows laptop (with G1 GC and per-trial setup). Try `-prof xperfasm` - it shows which parts of the disassembled code take most cpu time.

Comment: @apangin I added third update with link to GitHub repo. Maybe source code with my parameters in linked repo give you the same results as mine. I will check `-prof xperfasm` and come back with the results in a while. @joop-eggen In third update i get increasing performance on linux machine. I don't rule out that the decreasing performance applies only to my machine, so it could be a false alarm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even after copying your benchmark verbatim from [GitHub](https://github.com/JakubBialy/javaloopbenchmark) and running with the same parameters, I still cannot reproduce the results. In my environment, JDK 14 performs as fast as JDK 8 (even a little bit faster). So, in this answer I'll analyze the difference between both versions basing on the disassembly of the compiled code.

First, let's take the most recent OpenJDK builds from the same vendor.
Here I compare [Liberica JDK 8u265+1](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-8-lts) and [Liberica JDK 14.0.2+13](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-14-current) for Windows 64 bit.

JMH scores are the following:

```
Benchmark                         (ELEMENTS)   Mode  Cnt    Score   Error  Units
IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop    10000000  thrpt   30  263,137 ± 0,484  ops/s  # JDK 8
IteratingBenchmark.cStyleForLoop    10000000  thrpt   30  264,406 ± 0,788  ops/s  # JDK 14
```

Now let's run JMH with built-in `-prof xperfasm` profiler to see the disassembly of the hottest part of the benchmark. Expectedly, ~99.5% CPU time is spent in C2-compiled `cStyleForLoop` method.

**Hottest region on JDK 8**

```
....[Hottest Region 1]..............................................................................
C2, level 4, codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop, version 574 (71 bytes) 

             0x0000028c5607fc5f: add     r10d,0fffffff9h
             0x0000028c5607fc63: lea     rax,[r12+rcx*8]
             0x0000028c5607fc67: mov     ebx,80000000h
             0x0000028c5607fc6c: cmp     r9d,r10d
             0x0000028c5607fc6f: cmovl   r10d,ebx
             0x0000028c5607fc73: mov     r9d,1h
             0x0000028c5607fc79: cmp     r10d,1h
         ╭   0x0000028c5607fc7d: jle     28c5607fccch
         │   0x0000028c5607fc7f: nop                       ;*lload_2
         │                                                 ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@15 (line 25)
  0,07%  │↗  0x0000028c5607fc80: movsxd  rbx,dword ptr [rax+r9*4+10h]
  0,06%  ││  0x0000028c5607fc85: add     rbx,r8
  8,93%  ││  0x0000028c5607fc88: movsxd  rcx,r9d
  0,41%  ││  0x0000028c5607fc8b: movsxd  r8,dword ptr [rax+rcx*4+2ch]
 25,02%  ││  0x0000028c5607fc90: movsxd  rdi,dword ptr [rax+rcx*4+14h]
  0,10%  ││  0x0000028c5607fc95: movsxd  rsi,dword ptr [rax+rcx*4+18h]
  8,56%  ││  0x0000028c5607fc9a: movsxd  rbp,dword ptr [rax+rcx*4+28h]
  0,58%  ││  0x0000028c5607fc9f: movsxd  r13,dword ptr [rax+rcx*4+1ch]
  0,41%  ││  0x0000028c5607fca4: movsxd  r14,dword ptr [rax+rcx*4+20h]
  0,20%  ││  0x0000028c5607fca9: movsxd  rcx,dword ptr [rax+rcx*4+24h]
  8,85%  ││  0x0000028c5607fcae: add     rdi,rbx
  0,38%  ││  0x0000028c5607fcb1: add     rsi,rdi
  0,15%  ││  0x0000028c5607fcb4: add     r13,rsi
  8,57%  ││  0x0000028c5607fcb7: add     r14,r13
 13,76%  ││  0x0000028c5607fcba: add     rcx,r14
  5,51%  ││  0x0000028c5607fcbd: add     rbp,rcx
  8,50%  ││  0x0000028c5607fcc0: add     r8,rbp            ;*ladd
         ││                                                ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@24 (line 25)
  8,95%  ││  0x0000028c5607fcc3: add     r9d,8h            ;*iinc
         ││                                                ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@26 (line 24)
  0,40%  ││  0x0000028c5607fcc7: cmp     r9d,r10d
         │╰  0x0000028c5607fcca: jl      28c5607fc80h      ;*if_icmpge
         │                                                 ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@12 (line 24)
         ↘   0x0000028c5607fccc: cmp     r9d,edx
             0x0000028c5607fccf: jnl     28c5607fce4h
             0x0000028c5607fcd1: nop                       ;*lload_2
                                                           ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@15 (line 25)
             0x0000028c5607fcd4: movsxd  r10,dword ptr [rax+r9*4+10h]
             0x0000028c5607fcd9: add     r8,r10            ;*ladd
                                                           ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@24 (line 25)
....................................................................................................
```

**Hottest region on JDK 14**

```
....[Hottest Region 1]..............................................................................
c2, level 4, codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop, version 622 (147 bytes) 

                                                                         ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@23 (line 25)
               0x000001e844438f72:   mov     r11d,r10d
               0x000001e844438f75:   add     r11d,0fffffff9h
               0x000001e844438f79:   lea     rax,[r12+r9*8]
               0x000001e844438f7d:   mov     ebx,1h
               0x000001e844438f82:   cmp     r11d,1h
               0x000001e844438f86:   jle     1e8444390c0h                ;*goto {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                                         ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@29 (line 24)
         ╭     0x000001e844438f8c:   jmp     1e844438ffah
         │     0x000001e844438f8e:   nop
  0,04%  │↗    0x000001e844438f90:   mov     rsi,r8                      ;*lload_2 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         ││                                                              ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@15 (line 25)
  0,04%  ││ ↗  0x000001e844438f93:   movsxd  rdx,dword ptr [rax+rbx*4+10h]
  8,41%  ││ │  0x000001e844438f98:   movsxd  rbp,dword ptr [rax+rbx*4+14h]
  1,23%  ││ │  0x000001e844438f9d:   movsxd  r13,dword ptr [rax+rbx*4+18h]
  0,03%  ││ │  0x000001e844438fa2:   movsxd  r8,dword ptr [rax+rbx*4+2ch]
 23,87%  ││ │  0x000001e844438fa7:   movsxd  r11,dword ptr [rax+rbx*4+28h]
  8,22%  ││ │  0x000001e844438fac:   movsxd  r9,dword ptr [rax+rbx*4+24h]
  1,25%  ││ │  0x000001e844438fb1:   movsxd  rcx,dword ptr [rax+rbx*4+20h]
  0,14%  ││ │  0x000001e844438fb6:   movsxd  r14,dword ptr [rax+rbx*4+1ch]
  0,28%  ││ │  0x000001e844438fbb:   add     rdx,rsi
  7,82%  ││ │  0x000001e844438fbe:   add     rbp,rdx
  1,14%  ││ │  0x000001e844438fc1:   add     r13,rbp
  0,17%  ││ │  0x000001e844438fc4:   add     r14,r13
 14,57%  ││ │  0x000001e844438fc7:   add     rcx,r14
 11,05%  ││ │  0x000001e844438fca:   add     r9,rcx
  5,26%  ││ │  0x000001e844438fcd:   add     r11,r9
  6,32%  ││ │  0x000001e844438fd0:   add     r8,r11                      ;*ladd {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         ││ │                                                            ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@24 (line 25)
  8,45%  ││ │  0x000001e844438fd3:   add     ebx,8h                      ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         ││ │                                                            ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@26 (line 24)
  1,15%  ││ │  0x000001e844438fd6:   cmp     ebx,edi
         │╰ │  0x000001e844438fd8:   jl      1e844438f90h                ;*if_icmpge {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │  │                                                            ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@12 (line 24)
         │  │  0x000001e844438fda:   mov     r11,qword ptr [r15+110h]    ; ImmutableOopMap {rax=Oop xmm0=Oop xmm1=Oop }
         │  │                                                            ;*goto {reexecute=1 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │  │                                                            ; - (reexecute) codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@29 (line 24)
  0,00%  │  │  0x000001e844438fe1:   test    dword ptr [r11],eax         ;*goto {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │  │                                                            ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@29 (line 24)
         │  │                                                            ;   {poll}
  0,02%  │  │  0x000001e844438fe4:   cmp     ebx,dword ptr [rsp]
         │ ╭│  0x000001e844438fe7:   jnl     1e844439028h
  0,00%  │ ││  0x000001e844438fe9:   mov     rsi,r8
         │ ││  0x000001e844438fec:   vmovq   r8,xmm0
         │ ││  0x000001e844438ff1:   vmovq   rdx,xmm1
  0,01%  │ ││  0x000001e844438ff6:   mov     r11d,dword ptr [rsp]
         ↘ ││  0x000001e844438ffa:   mov     ecx,r10d
           ││  0x000001e844438ffd:   sub     ecx,ebx
           ││  0x000001e844438fff:   add     ecx,0fffffff9h
  0,00%    ││  0x000001e844439002:   mov     r9d,1f40h
           ││  0x000001e844439008:   cmp     r9d,ecx
           ││  0x000001e84443900b:   mov     edi,1f40h
           ││  0x000001e844439010:   cmovnle edi,ecx
  0,02%    ││  0x000001e844439013:   add     edi,ebx
           ││  0x000001e844439015:   vmovq   xmm0,r8
           ││  0x000001e84443901a:   vmovq   xmm1,rdx
           ││  0x000001e84443901f:   mov     dword ptr [rsp],r11d
  0,01%    │╰  0x000001e844439023:   jmp     1e844438f93h
           ↘   0x000001e844439028:   vmovq   rdx,xmm1
               0x000001e84443902d:   cmp     ebx,r10d
               0x000001e844439030:   jnl     1e844439043h
               0x000001e844439032:   nop                                 ;*lload_2 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                                         ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@15 (line 25)
               0x000001e844439034:   movsxd  r11,dword ptr [rax+rbx*4+10h]
               0x000001e844439039:   add     r8,r11                      ;*ladd {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                                         ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@24 (line 25)
               0x000001e84443903c:   inc     ebx                         ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                                         ; - codes.dbg.IteratingBenchmark::cStyleForLoop@26 (line 24)
....................................................................................................
```

As we can see, the loop body is compiled similarly on both JDKs:

- 8 loop iterations are unrolled;
- there are 8 loads from the array without bounds check, followed by 8 `add` instructions;
- the order of loads is a bit different, but all the addresses share the same or the adjacent cache line anyway.

The key difference is that on JDK 14 the loop iteration is split into two nested blocks. This is a result of [Loop strip mining](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8186027) optimization appeared in JDK 10. The idea of this optimization is to split the counted loop into the hot inner part without a safepoint poll, and an outer part with a safepoint poll instruction.

C2 JIT transforms the loop into something like

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 8000) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8000; j += 8) {
            int ix = i + j;
            int v0 = array[ix];
            int v1 = array[ix + 1];
            ...
            int v7 = array[ix + 7];
            sum += v0 + v1 + ... + v7;
        }
        safepoint_poll();
    }
```

Note that JDK 8 version does not have a safepoint poll inside the counted loop at all. On one hand, this can make the loop run faster. But on the other hand, this is actually bad for low latency applications, since the pause time may increase by the duration of the entire loop.

JDK 14 inserts a safepoint poll inside the loop. This *might* be a reason of a slow down you observe, but I don't really belive in this, since due to loop strip mining optimization, the safepoint polling is performed just once in 8000 iterations.

To verify this, you may disable safepoint polling with `-XX:-UseCountedLoopSafepoints` JVM option. In this case, JDK 14 compiled version will look almost identical to JDK 8 one. And so will the benchmark scores.

Comment: Really good description, good job @apangin. Unfortunetly i cannot got the hottest regions due to xperf error (xperf.exe - Error : The instruction at 0x00007FFFDFA8F88B referenced memory at 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. The memory could not be read.). I think the decreasing performance only occurs on my machine because it was similar or increasing on others. Your answet is enough for me. Thank you for your time.